# Meaning of "finding a tacit ally in" in this context

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Through his marriage and close relations with Poland, he was much
> influenced by Catholicism and he annulled a number of Lutheran
> elements in the liturgy with his own ‘Red Book’ liturgy of 1577. This
> greatly vexed the Protestant clergy and upper nobility, who soon **found
> a tacit ally in the king’s brother**, Duke Karl. (Bolds by me)
>
> A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

I want to know what does the phrase "found a tacit ally in the king’s brother" mean in this context? Does it mean that clergy and upper nobility come to a common ground that Duke Karl must rule the kingdom?

Comment: The quotation in your title is ungrammatical: "finding" would be the participle, but you should just quote the original phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "X found an ally in the king's brother" is "X discovered that the king's brother was an ally of X", i.e. "X discovered that the king's brother was on their side". "Tacit" you can get in a dictionary.

It's similar to an expression like "He found a friend in John", which means "He made friends with John" or "He found a friend, namely John". Another similar phrase is "To [find a friend in Jesus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33289961-find-a-friend-in-jesus---camp-adventure)", which means to come to view Jesus as your friend, i.e. to become a Christian. It's a metaphorical sense of "find": you are finding something inside a person, rather than literally discovering the person.